# How to debug templates variable in Sphinx autosummary?

Tags: python, jinja2, python-sphinx, autosummary

I'm trying to document a lib with an exotic structure. To ensure autosummary is working, I would need to overwrite the module.rst file. How can I print the variables used by autosummary to build the module page? (classes, objname, module etc...).

Specifically I would like to print in the console the list of classes that are called here:

```
{% block classes -%}
{% if classes -%}
.. rubric:: Classes

.. autosummary::
   :toctree:

   {% for item in classes -%}
   {% if item not in inherited_members -%}
   {{ item }}
   {% endif -%}
   {% endfor -%}

{% endif -%}
```